# multiprocessing counter output is strange, using lock

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a simple multiprocessing example.

I created a counter based on this, but I noticed a strange appearance during work.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value

counter = Value('i', 0)

def init(args):
    global counter
    counter = args

def analyze_data(args):
    global counter
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1
    print(counter.value)
    return args * 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = Value('i', 0)
    inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]*10

    p = Pool(initializer = init, initargs = (counter, ),  processes=24)
    i = p.map_async(analyze_data, inputs, chunksize = 1)
    i.wait()
    print(i.get())
```

## output

```
1
33
4
5
6
7
...
...
6160
6262
64
65
```

my expected, to 1,2,3,4,5,6...99,100 (Increase sequentially)

but, this output is strange.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to print the counter value within the lock block to avoid a *race condition* between unprotected print and incrementation of the value.

```
with counter.get_lock():
    counter.value += 1
    print(counter.value)
```

else:

- value can be changed by another process waiting on the lock *before* you print it (explains the double `3`)
- print statements can be executed in the wrong order (explains `60` & `61` inversion
- the fact that 62 is printed twice is related (I must admit I don't know exactly what happens but that's the same root cause)

That or make a copy (but leaving the print inside the lock makes display nicer and avoids that outputs are mixed. That fixes the double value issue but `60` and `61` swap case can still happen):

```
with counter.get_lock():
    counter.value += 1
    v = counter.value
print(v)
```